# Upload a File to PHP Server From Android Application gives java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out

Tags: java, php, android, httpurlconnection, socketexception

I am trying to upload file from my Android application. Below is the code:

This works fine in few mobile but I get error in some devices (Error below). I have taken the code from [this](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) website.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.test.Config;

public class CopyOfUploadMediaTask extends AsyncTask<File,Void,String>{

    private String sResponse = "";
    private Context context;

    private HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    private DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private String twoHyphens = "--";
    private String boundary = "*****";
    private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, serverResponseCode;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int maxBufferSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    private File file  = null;

    public CopyOfUploadMediaTask(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... arg0) {
        file = arg0[0];
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :");
            return "-1";
        }else{
            try { 
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                //URL has been changed for security reasons. dummy URL added
                URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/upload.php");

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", file.getName());

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + file.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                Log.d("File Name: ", file.getName());

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                sResponse = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + sResponse + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    if(sResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                        Log.d("Response", "ok");
                        return "1";
                    }else{
                        return "-2";
                    }
                }    

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return "-3";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
                return "-3";
            }
        }
        return sResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("Post Execute",result);
        if(result.trim().equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Uploaded: " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Failed for " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error I get is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:225)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readLine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:660)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:690) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1040)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
at com.panic.bgtasks.UploadMediaTask.doInBackground(UploadMediaTask.java:125)
at com.panic.bgtasks.UploadMediaTask.doInBackground(UploadMediaTask.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I am confused why it works for some and not for some. The result in post execute I get is -3, which suggest that MalformedURLException was caught. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not able to find the root cause.

Sorry I have less points and hence cannot add comment...Yeah it does respond quickly.. Also it worked well on few Android devices as well...

Comment: Does the PHP service respond quickly and well, when you send it a query through your web browser?

Comment: You have twice a return -3; So you do not know which exception occurs. Take a different value.